# How to stop Android Application under Eclipse in Mac OS X?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I have run android application on my Device. I want to stop this running application using DDMS.

On windows, I can see threads which are running on Android Device. like following image

> [image]

But on Mac OS X, I am missing such option, How can I get these ?

> [image]

Comment: yes it is possible in my mac i can see all the running app and i can stop. But i can see the app run from that mac device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that it's not the same device (4.1.2 vs 4.3) . Did you enable your device as debuggable?

It's in the developer's options and then check USB Debug option.

EDIT: See [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.ch/2013/02/secure-usb-debugging-in-android-422.html) how the security of USB debugging was improved since Android 4.2.2

Comment: On windows, I have Samsung Note, while on Mac I have samsung galaxy s4.But option is not connected with device. It is from eclipse.

Comment: And if you connect your Samsung Note on your mac, you don't see your app process ?

Comment: Because you can't see the processes list if your app is not set as debuggable or if your device is not configured for allowing USB Debugging. This is a new security feature introduced in Android 4.2.2 and you must manually enable it on your device by going to Settings > Developer options > USB Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you will select a device then after only it will enable that option. From your screenshots it is clearly seen that you have selected a device in Windows Platform while in Mac you haven't select it.

Comment: Click on that samsung device and then see.